# Symfony AMQP retry on success...?

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq, amqp

I currently have a communication between a site and an API, when I make a request to this API, AMQP launches a request and receives a response, however, it retries the request 3 times after getting a response in 200.
Any idea?
C.f my code + AMQP logs
NB: All 400 errors are due to the fact that the client already exists via the first request

```
$response = $this->backoffice->request('POST', 'client', [
                'json' => $data->jsonSerialize(),
            ]);
```

[image: AMQP logs]